# Showing MBProgress HUD inside SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller, mbprogresshud

I'm showing `MBProgressHUD` in menu bar of `SWRevealViewController`. When I scroll the menu and again open the menu the position of `MBProgressBar` changes.

I want the position to remain in the center of menu all the time.

```
hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.tableView animated:YES];
```

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: show hud on `tableView's superview` not on tableview or on `self.view`!!!